# IntelliJ Cucumber Java step definition not recognised

Tags: java, cucumber

I had tried to code cucumber 6 and its step definitions not detected. II using Alt + Enter to generate the step definitions.

TestRunner.java

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/Features/"},
        glue = {"com.nicholas.StepDefs"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}

)
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

Step Definitions:

```
public class Login_FE {
    @Given("Launch the homepage and login")
    public void launchTheHomepageAndLogin() {
        System.out.println("Launch browser");
    }

    @Given("user landing on phptravels.net")
    public void userLandingOnPhptravelsNet() {
        System.out.println("Launch browser");
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Scenario: Login to website                      # src/test/resources/Features/Login.feature:6
  Given Launch the homepage and login           # null
  Given user landing on phptravels.net          # null
  When enter login credential and click login   # null
  Then user redirect to phptravels.net homepage # null

at io.cucumber.core.runtime.TestCaseResultObserver.assertTestCasePassed(TestCaseResultObserver.java:69)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestCaseResultObserver.assertTestCasePassed(TestCaseResultObserver.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.lambda$runScenario$0(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:118)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:117)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:114)
    at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:77)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:15)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Please help me as i have no clue to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by clone the cucumber-java-skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

Just for info, I had the same error and while comparing everything with the cucumber-java skeleton I found that I only had a type within the `RunCucumberTest`:

```
@ConfigurationParameter(key = Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "de.powerstat.phplib.templateengine")
```

Within the packagename I had a typo - after fixing it the error was gone.